# Why do I only get 36% code coverage?

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, code-coverage

I have the following trigger with a test class which givese me only 36% of coverage. When i hardcode the message.toAddresses it becomes 100% but at the moment the code coverage stops at my SOQL see:

```
trigger beforeInsertOnCaseLoopKiller on Case (before insert) {
    // Will not process new email if there are at least 4 emails from
    // the same email address with the same subject and the previous email
    // was less than 5 minutes old.

    case[] c = trigger.new;

    case[] check = [select ID, CreatedDate, subject from Case where SuppliedEmail = :c[0].SuppliedEmail and subject = :c[0].subject and isclosed = false order by CreatedDate desc];
    system.debug(c[0].SuppliedEmail);
    system.debug(c[0].subject);               

    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    // Set recipients to two contact IDs.
    // Replace IDs with valid record IDs in your org.
    message.toAddresses = new String[] {[SELECT Loopkiller_Email_support__c FROM Loopkiller2__c LIMIT 1][0].Loopkiller_Email_support__c};
    message.optOutPolicy = 'FILTER';
    message.subject = 'Email loop caused';
    message.plainTextBody = 'An email loop has been caused by case '+c[0].subject + '\n' + 'This loop was generated by email adres '+ c[0].SuppliedEmail + '.';
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] messages = 
    new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> {message};
         Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(messages);

    if (results[0].success) {
        System.debug('The email was sent successfully.');
    } else {
        System.debug('The email failed to send: '
          + results[0].errors[0].message);
    }                
}
```

Test class

```
@isTest
public class beforeInsertOnCaseLoopkillerTestClass {

    static testmethod void LoopTest(){
        try{
            Case newcase1 = new Case(SuppliedEmail = 'test@test.com', subject = 'Test');
            insert newCase1;   
            Case newcase2 = new Case(SuppliedEmail = 'test@test.com', subject = 'Test');
            insert newCase2;   
            Case newcase3 = new Case(SuppliedEmail = 'test@test.com', subject = 'Test');
            insert newCase3;   
            Case newcase4 = new Case(SuppliedEmail = 'test@test.com', subject = 'Test');
            insert newCase4;   
            Case newcase5 = new Case(SuppliedEmail = 'test@test.com', subject = 'Test');
            insert newCase5;   
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
        }
    }     
}
```

Comment: There are some some unecessary things (putting `trigger.new` into a separate list, using a list initialization to capture the results of a query)  and red flags (working only with the first record of trigger.new) I see with your trigger, but I don't see anything that should stop the execution of your test given the code you've provided. Your use of try/catch in your test method is probably masking the issue you're running into. Remove it and try running your test again. Then, [edit] your question to include the exact text of your error message.

Comment: Also, your test doesn't directly create any `Loopkiller2__c` records. Do you have another trigger that creates a `Loopkiller2__c` record when a new `Case` is inserted? Your trigger also doesn't seem to do what your comments claim it does (I don't see any code that checks the number of emails with the same address and subject, nor code that actually checks a timestamp).

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/105256

Comment: The more I look at this, the more I think you need to step back from testing for the moment and focus on tackling the issues with your trigger. If you're familiar with unit testing, this could be an opportunity to practice Test-Driven Development (i.e. figure out what your goals are, come up with a plan on how you can measure whether or not you've accomplished your goals, and then write tests to check whether or not you've met your goals. Then, write code until all your tests pass).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code for fetching toAddress SELECT Loopkiller_Email_support__c FROM Loopkiller2__c LIMIT 1][0], Loopkiller_Email_support__c you are reading data from Loopkiller2__c  object but when the test class runs it wont be able to read data from that object.
Create a test record for Loopkiller2__c  object with the email address field set and then run code for inserting cases in your test class.